# Start fms with an application loaded automatically

Tags: flash-media-server, fms3

Is it possible at flash media server, to start an application automatically when the server starts?

Or a way to check if it running, and if it's not, make it start automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe it's `<LoadOnStartup>true</LoadOnStartup>` in Application.xml. You may also want to set `MaxAppIdleTime` to something appropriately large for your app, lest FMS unload it shortly after startup if no clients have connected.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I don't know how to define an instance of the application so it restarts with _definst_ instance. Any way to change it?